# Не работает KeyboardEvent 13 помогите

Tags: javascript

```
let setTask = document.querySelector('.input-task');

setTask.addEventListener('keyCode', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        let taskDiv = document.createElement('div');
        tasksDiv.textContent = setTask.value;
        setTask.appendChild(tasksDiv);
    }
});
```

Нужно, чтобы при вводе текста в `input`, при нажатии на кнопку Enter, создавался новый блок `div` с текстом из `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const setTask = document.querySelector('.input-task');

setTask.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    const taskDiv = document.createElement('div');
    taskDiv.textContent = this.value;
    setTask.after(taskDiv);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-task" />
```